# Error in My Hard Disk on Debian (OSSIM)

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, fsck, ossim

I have a Problem with my Debian (OSSIM), after a three days I can't create or edit any files, because of this issue:

```
root@ossim:~$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory `test': Read-only file system
```

so I boot the OS on live mode, using ubuntu, and running `fsck.ext3` command, but this command did't repair partition.

Partition Type is `EXT3` and these logs is in  the `kern.log`

```
[612904.370362]  [<ffffffff8106c8e4>] ? __local_bh_enable_ip+0x84/0x90
[612904.370367]  [<ffffffff814f4dbf>] ? packet_poll+0xbf/0x130
[612904.370370]  [<ffffffff81404009>] ? sock_poll+0x49/0x110
[612904.370375]  [<ffffffff811bc388>] ? do_sys_poll+0x2f8/0x540
[612904.370380]  [<ffffffff8109c260>] ? update_curr+0x90/0x120
[612904.370384]  [<ffffffff810a25bc>] ? pick_next_task_fair+0x19c/0x820
[612904.370388]  [<ffffffff810115dc>] ? __switch_to+0x15c/0x570
[612904.370394]  [<ffffffff810d15bf>] ? get_futex_key+0x1df/0x2c0
[612904.370398]  [<ffffffff811bb0f0>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x140/0x140
[612904.370402]  [<ffffffff8108c136>] ? atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
[612904.370405]  [<ffffffff81094479>] ? set_task_cpu+0x99/0x1a0
[612904.370408]  [<ffffffff8109f620>] ? check_preempt_wakeup+0x120/0x1d0
[612904.370411]  [<ffffffff81094225>] ? check_preempt_curr+0x85/0xa0
[612904.370413]  [<ffffffff81094254>] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x14/0xd0
[612904.370416]  [<ffffffff810966a3>] ? try_to_wake_up+0xd3/0x2d0
[612904.370419]  [<ffffffff810d1c6f>] ? futex_wake+0x6f/0x120
[612904.370422]  [<ffffffff810d1bdd>] ? wake_futex+0x5d/0x80
[612904.370425]  [<ffffffff810d43a6>] ? do_futex+0x8d6/0xb60
[612904.370429]  [<ffffffff8101b555>] ? read_tsc+0x5/0x20
[612904.370433]  [<ffffffff810c7a12>] ? ktime_get_ts+0x42/0xe0
[612904.370436]  [<ffffffff811bc68d>] ? SyS_poll+0x5d/0xf0
[612904.370439]  [<ffffffff8151164d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
[612904.370441] Code: 89 f8 48 83 fa 20 72 7e 40 38 fe 7c 35 48 83 ea 20 48 83 ea 20 4c 8b 06 4c 8b 4e 08 4c 8b 56 10 4c 8b 5e 18 48 8d 76 20 4c 89 07 <4c> 89 4f 08 4c 89 57 10 4c 89 5f 18 48 8d 7f 20 73 d4 83 c2 20 
[641135.553528] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #29: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (15010 != 256)
[641135.570759] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[641135.572465] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[641135.572492] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #16: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (26098 != 256)
[641135.574741] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #31: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (8378 != 256)
[641135.586395] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #15: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (25005 != 256)
[641135.587699] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #25: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (26561 != 256)
[641135.627263] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #22: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (27873 != 256)
[641135.627774] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #19: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (25760 != 256)
[641135.628510] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #34: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (8378 != 256)
[641135.628975] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_iget:4063: inode #20: comm sftp-server: bad extra_isize (27810 != 256)
```

I'm so confused, someone can help me?

## Update

`dumpe2fs` command result

```
root@ossim:~$ dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1

dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          9981b98b-d1d4-440a-b75f-abf4290edf7a
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              32112640
Block count:              128449792
Reserved block count:     6422488
Free blocks:              107962759
Free inodes:              31089277
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      993
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Sat Jan 23 16:37:32 2016
Last mount time:          Sat Mar 30 09:30:15 2019
Last write time:          Sat Mar 30 09:30:15 2019
Mount count:              15
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sun Mar 11 14:42:25 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          6649 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1130651
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      f5584173-9714-49d9-a9a3-b255028e51e5
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             128M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x0cb67c3d
Journal start:            27337
```

Comment: Are you sure it's ext3? Maybe you'll have more luck with the fsck.ext4 tool.

Comment: `df -TH` command  says type is `ext3`

Comment: That just checks how it's mounted. Try `dump2efs -h /dev/sda1`. The "Filesystem features" will determine if any ext4 features are in use (esp. `extra_isize` in your case).

Comment: I updated the question with this commnad

Comment: You're right, this looks like ext3. `fsck.ext3 -f /dev/sda1` _should_ fix any problems...

Comment: unfortunately this command didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check fstab entry for this device, I think it is updated wrongly, dump2fs shows filesystem like ext4 but you said in df it is showing ext3, it is indicator of wrong filesystem type in fstab. Even your errors also shows filesystem looks like ext4.